# Django: TypeError preventing attaching a bytes-like object to email

Tags: django, email, django-email

I am trying to use xlsxwriter to generate a xlsx file and then send it as an attachment in email. Here is what I have now:

```
def WriteToExcel(project):
    output = BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)

    #putting in data

    workbook.close()
    xlsx_data = output.getvalue()
    # xlsx_data contains the Excel file
    return xlsx_data

def project_email (request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id = project_id)
    xlsx_data = WriteToExcel(project)

    message = EmailMessage("Heading", 'Here is the message.', 'HOST', ['SAMPLE@gmail.com'])

    message.attach_file(xlsx_data)
    message.send()
```

And when I tried to send the email, I have the following error:

> TypeError at /projstatus/1/email
>
> cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Is there any way that I could go around it? Like, make the xlsx file non-binary or if there is a function in email to attach binary file?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I figured out this problem. You just need to something like this:

```
def project_email (request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id = project_id)
    xlsx_data = WriteToExcel(project)

    message = EmailMessage("Heading", 'Here is the message.', 'HOST', ['SAMPLE@gmail.com'])

    message.attach("Report.xlsx", xlsx_data, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    message.send()
```

I will just left this here in case other people is wondering the same thing